# why this code get different result,input with different order in shell?

Tags: erlang

consider the code bleow:

```
-module(add_two).
-compile(export_all).

start()->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Pid = spawn_link(add_two, loop, []),
    register(add_two, Pid),
    ok.

request()->
    add_two ! bad,
    receive
        {'EXIT', _Pid, Reason} -> io:format("self:~w~n", [{error, Reason}]);
        {Result}               -> io:format("result:~w~n", [Result])
    after
        1000->timeout
    end.

loop()->
    receive
        bad                 -> exit(nogoodreason_bad);
        {request, Pid, Msg} -> Pid ! {result, Msg + 2}
    end,
    loop().
```

**when I test the code above in shell,I get two different results with different input order,but why?**

first input order :

```
Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> add_two:request(ddd).
** exception error: undefined function add_two:request/1
2> add_two:start().
ok
3> add_two:request(). 
self:{error,nogoodreason_bad}
ok
```

second input order:

```
Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> add_two:start().
ok
2> add_two:request(ddd).
** exception error: undefined function add_two:request/1
3> add_two:request().
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  add_two:request/0 (add_two.erl, line 11)
```

Comment: Code that is completely devoid of whitespace and indented haphazardly is very difficult to read. I've cleaned things up for you in this instance. Please follow suit in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `add_two:request(ddd)` makes the shell process die, taking add_two down with it, due to the `spawn_link()` call. You can confirm this by checking the shell's pid before and after an exception. It doesn't even have to involve the `add_two` module:

```
12> self().
<0.61.0>
13> 2+2.
4
14> self().
<0.61.0>
15> 1/0.
** exception error: bad argument in an arithmetic expression
     in operator  '/'/2
        called as 1 / 0
16> self().
<0.69.0>
17>
```

You can avoid this effect either by calling `spawn` instead of `spawn_link`, or trapping and handling exits in the spawned process.